# Getting sample project for iOS using Azure mobile serveice authorization

Tags: swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I was't able to download the quick-start project from the Azure console. Can any one provides a sample project for authentication/Authorization using Azure Active Directory. I am following this tutorial which uses the quick-start.

Here's [a link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-users/) to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the quickstart from the same (roughly) page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/

You can also download the quickstart from the portal - go to your azure app service, click on Tools -> Quickstarts -> Mobile Apps, then select the iOS platform and download the project.

You can also get it from our Quickstart repository, although that needs a little more work to get going - https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts

There are also samples in our samples repository: https://github.com/azure-samples